# Using find to look for a directory and remove its subdirectories

Tags: find, directory, rm

Let's say I have a list of nested directories that looks like this:

```
./x1/mf/dir1
./x1/mf/dir2
./x1/mf/file1
./x2/mf/dir3
./x2/mf/file2
...
```

I want to remove all the subdirectories of every `mf` directory. Meaning `dir1`, `dir2`, `dir3` in the previous example.

I know that

```
find . -type d -name "mf"
```

will return a list of all the directories called `mf`. And `ls -d */` returns all the subdirectories in the current directory. So I tried

```
find . -type d -name "mf" -exec ls -d /* {} \;
```

to list the desired directories, but it would actually print the directories inside `/`. I was planning to pipe the resulting list to `xargs rm -r` to do the removal afterwards.

Comment: try `find . -type d -path '*/mf/*'` and then add `-exec rm -r {} +`....

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Setting up test directories and files:

```
$ mkdir -p x{1..3}/mf/dir{1..3}
$ touch x{1..3}/mf/file{1..3}
$ tree
.
|-- x1
|   `-- mf
|       |-- dir1
|       |-- dir2
|       |-- dir3
|       |-- file1
|       |-- file2
|       `-- file3
|-- x2
|   `-- mf
|       |-- dir1
|       |-- dir2
|       |-- dir3
|       |-- file1
|       |-- file2
|       `-- file3
`-- x3
    `-- mf
        |-- dir1
        |-- dir2
        |-- dir3
        |-- file1
        |-- file2
        `-- file3
```

Then find all directories that has `mf` in its path and delete them. The `-depth` does a depth-first traversal, so that `find` doesn't try to enter directories that it has already deleted.  We also print the names of all directories that are deleted.

```
$ find . -depth -type d -path "*/mf/*" -print -exec rm -rf {} +
./x1/mf/dir1
./x1/mf/dir2
./x1/mf/dir3
./x2/mf/dir1
./x2/mf/dir2
./x2/mf/dir3
./x3/mf/dir1
./x3/mf/dir2
./x3/mf/dir3
```

Now:

```
$ tree
.
|-- x1
|   `-- mf
|       |-- file1
|       |-- file2
|       `-- file3
|-- x2
|   `-- mf
|       |-- file1
|       |-- file2
|       `-- file3
`-- x3
    `-- mf
        |-- file1
        |-- file2
        `-- file3
```

Comment: Which destro are you using? I tried the command on Ubuntu and got:  

    find: warning: the -d option is deprecated; please use -depth instead, because the latter is a     POSIX-compliant feature.
    find: paths must precede expression: .

with no output.
(I can't get the comment formatting right :P )

Comment: @ditek This happened to be specific to the `find` on OpenBSD, but I have updated the answer to work with GNU/POSIX `find` too.

Comment: It works now, thanks. I was wondering about the `+` at the end of the command. I usually use `';'`. Is there any difference?

Comment: The difference is that with `\;` the `rm` would be executed once for each found directory, while with `+` it would be executed once with as many directories as possible (if there were thousands, several `rm` runs would still be done, but not once per directory).

Answer (score 0):

I strongly suggest using this to `ls` before `rm -fr`ing for obvious reasons:

```
find . -type d -name "mf" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -I haystack find haystack -type d -exec rm -fr {} \;
```

Example:

```
$ tree
.
├── bar
│   ├── foo
│   │   ├── bar
│   │   └── baz
│   └── freeble
├── baz
│   ├── foo
│   │   ├── bar
│   │   └── baz
│   └── freeble
└── quux
    ├── foo
    │   ├── bar
    │   └── baz
    └── freeble

15 directories, 0 files
$ find . -type d -name "foo" -print0 | xargs -0 -n1 -I haystack find haystack -type d -maxdepth 0 -exec rm -fr {} \;
$ tree
.
├── bar
│   └── freeble
├── baz
│   └── freeble
└── quux
    └── freeble

6 directories, 0 files
```

Comment: why not just `find . -type d -name "mf" -exec rm -rf {} \;`? Also, in your example you use `foo` and `bar`, but your suggestion does not. The solution you propose and the example you give should be consistent.

Comment: @Centimane Only the subdirectories of the `mf` directories were to be deleted, not the files of the `mf` directories.

Comment: Your example swaps `mf` with `foo`, and the directory `foo` was deleted.

Comment: Still begs the question why you didn't take the simpler: `find . -type d -name "mf" -exec rm -rf {}/* \;`

Comment: @Centimane You are talking to the wrong person.

Comment: @Kusalananda my mistake!